# Set the react-bootstrap checkbox to uncheck state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, react-bootstrap

I am a newbie to `react` and I was not able to figure how to reset the checkbox to uncheck stat on resetting. I have used the `react-bootstrap form` and need to reset the checkboxes to default state on a button click.

```
export const pitch: FC<pitchProps> = ({ pitchData, totalNoOfData }) => {
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
 const [totalRows, setTotalRows] = useState(totalNoOfData);

  const formData = {
  searchData: pitchParam.searchString,
  searchCriteria: pitchParam.searchStatus,
   };

   const handleFormData = (e: any) => {
    if (e.target.type === "checkbox") {
      e.target.checked
    ? formData.searchCriteria.push(e.target.id)
    : (formData.searchCriteria = formData.searchCriteria.filter(
        (item: any) => item !== e.target.id
      ));
   } else {
    formData.searchData = e.target.value;
     }
   };

return (
<div className={styles.mainTableContainer}>
  <div className="d-flex ml-2">
    <Form className="w-100">
      <Form.Row>
        <Form.Label className={styles.label}>NEW </Form.Label>

        <Form.Check
          className={styles.checkbox}
          type="checkbox"
          id="OLD"
          onChange={(e: any) => handleFormData(e)}
        />
        <Form.Label className={styles.label}> OLD </Form.Label>

        <Form.Check
          className={styles.checkbox}
          type="checkbox"
          id="OUTDATED"
          onChange={(e: any) => handleFormData(e)}
        />
        <Form.Label className={styles.label}>OUTDATED </Form.Label>
        <Form.Check
          className={styles.checkbox}
          type="checkbox"
          id="SUCCESS"
          onChange={(e: any) => handleFormData(e)}
        />
      </Form.Row>
    </Form>
  </div>
</div>
);
};
```

Comment: Do you need to uncheck the checkbox within "searchData" function?

Comment: not  on searchData i have button in another component which sets on the redux state to reset then need to reset this checkbox to uncheck state

Comment: i have set the state but not yet handled in this component as i was not able to figure it out.. , its also ok if uncheck  happens on searchData function itself

Comment: if I got the problem, do you need to implement another button with the handler to uncheck the checkbox?

Comment: yes @novonimo tats wat i need ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `checkbox` component is not fully controlled by you, so it is an uncontrolled component.

##### Solution 1 : using reference

As your `checkbox` is controlled by the bootstrap-form you need to create a reference and pass it to the checkbox to manipulate the `checked` value:

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
// reset of the codes

// in the pitch component
const checkboxRef = useRef(null);
```

Now, pass the `checkboxRef` into the checkbox component within `ref` property:

```
<Form.Check
   type={type}
   id={`default-${type}`}
   label={`default ${type}`}   
   ref={checkboxRef}     // <--------- here
/>
```

Now, try to add another button with a reset handler:

```
const handleResetCheckbox = () => {
   checkboxRef.current.checked = false
}
```

##### Solultion 2 : using react key

You can also do the same with a different approach by using the React component's **key**.
If the key gets changes, react will remove the component and create a new one. so you can use this key property to uncheck (reset) the checkboxes:

define a `key` with `useState` and pass it to the checkbox component:

```
const [key, setKey] = useState(false)

<Form.Check
   key={key}            // <--------- added here
   type={type}
   id={`default-${type}`}
   label={`default ${type}`}   
/>
```

Now, in the `handleResetCheckbox`, change the key:

```
const handleResetCheckbox = () => {
   setKey(prevState => !prevState)
}
```

So, when you reset the checkbox, the key will change then React will remove the old checkbox and render a new one. more information in [React](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key) documentation.